# "no such table: users" when testing and using Bookshelf / Knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to run a simple test using Mocha and my Bookshelf / Knex model, however I'm getting the error "Unhandled rejection Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users". Note that I'm trying to use in memory SQLite.

Here's my Knexfile:

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: ':memory:'
    }
  },

  test: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: '172.18.0.2',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'staging_db',
      charset  : 'utf8'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
      user: process.env.DB_USER || 'usr',
      password: process.env.DB_PWD || '',
      database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'db',
      charset  : 'utf8'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

Database.js:

```
var config      = require('../knexfile.js');  
var env         = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';  
var knex        = require('knex')(config[env]);

knex.migrate.latest([config]);

let bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

bookshelf.plugin('registry'); // Resolve circular dependencies with relations

// Export bookshelf for use elsewhere
module.exports = bookshelf;
```

And my User model:

```
let bookshelf = require('../config/database');

require('./role');

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    role: function() {
        return this.hasOne(Role);
    }
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model('user', User);
```

And my test:

```
var User = require('../../models/user'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect;

describe('User model', function () {

    it('should return empty set before adding anything', () => {
        expect(User.collection().count()).to.equal(0); 
    });

});
```

Am I missing something?

### UPDATE

Adding the migration file:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('roles', function (table) {
        //this creates an id column as auto incremented primary key
        table.increments();
        table.string('description', 45).notNullable();
    })
    .createTable('users', function (table) {
        table.increments();
        table.string('name', 60);
        table.string('password', 45);
        table.integer('role_id').unsigned();
        table.foreign('role_id').references('roles.id');
    });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users').dropTable('roles');
};
```

Comment: Neither Bookshelf nor Knex do create tables automatically. Are you creating this 'users' table (with knex Schema Builder, for example)?

Comment: I've created a migration file using Knex CLI, I've update the question with the code of this migration.

Comment: Note that `knex.migrate.latest()` is asynchronous. You may be experiencing a race condition with the test running before the table gets created.

Comment: Do I have any options to run the tests and undo the changes automatically so I don't have to run migrations every time? I tried to use Sinon.JS sandbox assuming it works like this, but I got an error saying that the method does not exist (actually I don't even know how it could work if the models doesn't have the table schema).

Comment: I've tried such "clean state" approach before, but that just made my tests slower and, surprisingly, unreliable. Currently I just add `before()` clauses to my tests ensuring stuff that should or should not be present in the database. Some may think this too heterodox but my needs got fulfilled.

Comment: Do you usually test your models directly or do you use to test your APIs to indirectly test the model?

Comment: I do both. I have tests for each API but also test into the model level. API testing has lower granularity than model testing. So if a model expose some complex logic it is easier to cover most paths if testing it directly.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'll review the tests I'm doing and replace the one that checks if the database is empty, thus not require the recreation of the DB and the execution of migrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: your test is wrong: `count()` returns a count *promise* not the count itself. So change your test to:

```
it('should return empty set before adding anything', function(done) {
    User
    .collection()
    .count()
    .then(count => {
        expect(count).to.equal(0);
        done()
    })
    .catch(err => done(err)); 
});
```

Second: You have a race condition between the test and the migration.

If you enable Knex debug mode on your `knexfile.js`

```
//...
development: {
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: ':memory:'
  },
  debug: true
},
//...
```

You will get

```
$ ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha ./test/user.js
Knex:warning - sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).


  User model
[ { sql: 'select * from sqlite_master where type = \'table\' and name = ?',
    output: [Function: output],
    bindings: [ 'knex_migrations' ] } ]
[ { sql: 'create table if not exists "knex_migrations" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "name" varchar(255), "batch" integer, "migration_time" datetime)',
    bindings: [] } ]
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '7186321c-92b5-416c-8a5f-304118e47a0d',
  sql: 'select count(*) as "count" from "users"' }
[ { sql: 'select * from sqlite_master where type = \'table\' and name = ?',
    output: [Function: output],
    bindings: [ 'knex_migrations_lock' ] } ]
    1) should return empty set before adding anything
[ { sql: 'create table if not exists "knex_migrations_lock" ("is_locked" integer)',
    bindings: [] } ]

{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '7ebd63cc-1070-4422-b664-47e28b58de15',
  sql: 'select * from "knex_migrations_lock"' }

  0 passing (62ms)
  1 failing

  1) User model should return empty set before adding anything:
     select count(*) as "count" from "users" - SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users
  Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users
```

Note the `count()` query happened while the migration was still checking if migration tables existed.

An easy (and overly ugly) fix is to add some delays to the test:

```
describe('User model', function () {

    this.timeout(20000);

    before(function (done) {
        setTimeout(() => done(), 200);  // 200ms was enough on my env
    })

    it('should return empty set before adding anything', function (done) {
        User.collection().count()
        .then(count => {
            expect(count).to.equal(0);
            done()
        })
        .catch(err => done(err)); 
    });

});
```

And you will happily get

```
$ ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha ./test/user.js
Knex:warning - sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).


  User model
    ✓ should return empty set before adding anything


  1 passing (225ms)
```

Note the test took slightly over 200ms to run.

Another possible approach could be to add the migrations to the `before()` clause. That would enable you to use `await` on them.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on using `await`, however it can't be used outside an `async` function and if I do something like this `(async ()=>{
   await knex.migrate.latest([config]);
})(); ` the behaviour seems to be the same as before as it says that the table couldn't be found.

Comment: I said using `await` inside `before()` callback. There you could have something like `await migrations(); done()`. Of course, that means giving up the idea of automatically calling migrations on startup, that is currently broken anyway.